# How can i make my header not move along with my slides in fullpagejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I created a slide in fullpagejs but the header moves along with the slide which isnt good. How can i make the header continue to appear within the background image/slides without moving with the slides?

If i take the header out of the background section it stays while the slide moves, but it then creates a white space at the top which i dont want.  I've tried to fix it with position absolute and relative but none seem to work need help.

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){

//  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
//     sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
//     slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
//     controlArrows: false
//     // more options here
// });


// variables
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');



// toggle menu 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
});



// fullpage customization
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['firstSection'],

  loopBottom: false,
  afterRender: function () {
    setInterval (function () {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight ();
    }, 5000);
  },
  // sectionSelector: '.vertical-scrolling',
  // slideSelector: '.horizontal-scrolling',
  navigation: true,
  slidesNavigation: true,
  controlArrows: false,

  
    

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $header_top.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .3)');
    $nav.css('background', 'rgba(0, 47, 77, .25)');
    setInterval(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
    }, 5000);
    if (index == 1) {
        $('#fp-nav').hide();
      }
  },

  
}); 
});
```

```css
#homepage {
  position: relative; }
  #homepage .slider {
    background-size: cover !important; }
    #homepage .slider .hero {
      padding: 0 25px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: calc(100vh - 10%); }
      #homepage .slider .hero .header {
        padding-top: 20px;
        flex: 1 1 70px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between; }
        #homepage .slider .hero .header .logo img {
          cursor: pointer;
          image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; }
        #homepage .slider .hero .header i {
          color: #fff;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<div class="container">
            <div id="homepage" class="main">
                <div id="fullpage">
                <section class="section">
                    <section class="slider slide"  style="background: url('http://neonrobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/unsplash-1.jpg') center center;">
                        <div class="hero">
                            <div class="header">
                                <div class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"></div>
                                <i id="menu-open" class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="welcome">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="hero-headings">Hello.</div>
                                    <div class="hero-description"></div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients">
                            <div class="padding25">
                                <div class="clients-intro">Our Clients. &nbsp; <i class="fa   fa-angle-right"></i><i class="fa   fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                <div class="clients-logos">sds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="slider slide" style="background: url('http://neonrobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/unsplash-1.jpg') center center;">
                        <div class="hero">
                            <div class="header">
                                <div class="logo"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
                                <i id="menu-open" class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="welcome">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="hero-headings">Hello.</div>
                                    <div class="hero-description"></div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients">
                            <div class="padding25">
                                <div class="clients-intro">Our Clients. &nbsp; <i class="fa   fa-angle-right"></i><i class="fa   fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                <div class="clients-logos">sds</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </section>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you can put your header before slider

Comment: yes i can but then it if i do that the header no longer  appears within the background image instead it appears on top. I want it to appear within the backgrounf image.

Comment: add header css property use position fixed if u want to top fixed and give z-index if you required and check

Comment: I've tried that before. t works but not well. it appears within the image but the problem with that is the logo and nav icon move away from the actual position which is then hard to correct. And im also tring to avoid the fixed position.

Comment: As easy as adding the css style: `position:fixed` and place the element outside the plugin's wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### #1

What about header like menu from [fullpage.js main page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?

I've added this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-active">
        <a href="#" rel="noopener">
            <span>Wordpress Theme</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#examples" class="show-examples">Examples</a></li>
    <li>
        <a rel="noopener" href="#">Docs</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="twitter-share">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-line" style="width: 166.953px; left: 20px;"></li>
</ul>
```

and some of css:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 70;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#menu a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 1.1em 1.1em;
}
.menu-active {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bz6mcL6f/). It looks more simpler because I missed some part of css, but I think you will get the idea.

#### #2

I'm not sure that it is documented behavior but I found another more simpler option - just add this:

```
<div class="fp-slidesNav top" style="color:white">
  Header
</div>
```

right after `<section class="section">`. Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bz6mcL6f/1/).